# Spring boot : integration with jasypt library

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

I have a trouble at integrating jasypt library inside a spring boot + spring data jpa + spring security application.
Below the error stacktrace.

```
:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 1.3.1.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::

2016-04-07 10:53:17.797  INFO 4696 --- [           main] com.tess2i.service.UserServiceIntTest    : Starting UserServiceIntTest on PCFX150 with PID 4696 (C:\ffournel\eclipseM\workspace\TessiCommunication\target\test-classes started by ffournel in C:\ffournel\eclipseM\workspace\TessiCommunication)
2016-04-07 10:53:17.802 DEBUG 4696 --- [           main] com.tess2i.service.UserServiceIntTest    : Running with Spring Boot v1.3.1.RELEASE, Spring v4.2.4.RELEASE
2016-04-07 10:53:17.803  INFO 4696 --- [           main] com.tess2i.service.UserServiceIntTest    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-04-07 10:53:21.160 DEBUG 4696 --- [           main] com.tess2i.config.AsyncConfiguration     : Creating Async Task Executor
2016-04-07 10:53:21.470 DEBUG 4696 --- [           main] com.tess2i.config.MetricsConfiguration   : Registering JVM gauges
2016-04-07 10:53:21.484 DEBUG 4696 --- [           main] com.tess2i.config.MetricsConfiguration   : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2016-04-07 10:53:22.961  INFO 4696 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.tess2i.config.WebConfigurer          : Web application configuration, using profiles: []
2016-04-07 10:53:22.963 DEBUG 4696 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.tess2i.config.WebConfigurer          : Initializing Metrics registries
2016-04-07 10:53:22.969 DEBUG 4696 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.tess2i.config.WebConfigurer          : Registering Metrics Filter
2016-04-07 10:53:22.969 DEBUG 4696 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.tess2i.config.WebConfigurer          : Registering Metrics Servlet
2016-04-07 10:53:22.971  INFO 4696 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.tess2i.config.WebConfigurer          : Web application fully configured
2016-04-07 10:53:23.437 DEBUG 4696 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.tess2i.config.DatabaseConfiguration  : Configuring Datasource
2016-04-07 10:53:23.979 DEBUG 4696 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.tess2i.config.DatabaseConfiguration  : Configuring Liquibase
2016-04-07 10:53:23.995 DEBUG 4696 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.t.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase     : Starting Liquibase synchronously
2016-04-07 10:53:25.214 DEBUG 4696 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.t.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase     : Started Liquibase in 1219 ms
2016-04-07 10:53:26.151 ERROR 4696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.tess2i.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tess2i.repository.UserRepository com.tess2i.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1b2f727' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1b2f727': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.jasypt.hibernate.type.EncryptedStringType not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4659) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5281) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
```

The main error is  :

```
org.jasypt.hibernate.type.EncryptedStringType not present
```

Whereas I have in my pom.xml all necessary dependencies (I suppose), that is to say :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I really don't know what to do .... do I need to add a configurer for this at spring boot starting ?

Comment: Well, the error comes from a wrong version of jasypt librairie. This error is normal. I go further then

Comment: Hum, problem still exists. But inside source code of jasypt-hibernate4.jar, there is a reference to type "org.jasypt.hibernate.type.EncryptedStringType" which doesn't exists ! The type is org.jasypt.hibernate4.type.EncryptedStringType. Any Idea ? Why does it loads an non existing class ??

Comment: can you post your sample code somewhere, so that we can take a deep look at it?